# What kind of Hashing algorithm is my Linux using?

Tags: algorithms

In Kali Linux, I found an unknown hash algorithm used to encrypt the Kali Linux password.

> root:$y$j9T$J3nInhusIQkrmvCnX8tlo.$KduXmrDY7wv3o2P/k9t35adUH5XWUBYngo1Wxypy2X.:18749:0:99999:7:::

My Question is: What type of hash is it? It doesn't seem to be MD5 nor SHA-512.

Comment: Although the _question is not identical_ to the duplicate question, the duplicate answers this question.

Comment: Thanks bro..I was actually searching for something like this...